# how to change string time to rails date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have date as `"Wed, 29 Jun 2016"` and time in `"11:35 PM"` format 
 how can i create a date time object with it?

something like what Time.current does.

Comment: We'd like to see your attempt to solve this. Showing effort is very important, otherwise it looks like you didn't even try and want us to solve the problem for you. Please read "[ask]", including the linked pages, "[mcve]", and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Comment: I did try multiple attempts and i don't even know if i am moving in correct direction. thats why i didnt post my attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually pretty simple if your date can be parsed:

```
DateTime.parse("Wed, 29 Jun 2016 11:35 PM")
# => Wed, 29 Jun 2016 23:35:00 +0000
```

You can then use that in any capacity you'd use any other date/time.

Comment: Its working like charm, I couldnt find this in DateTime class documentation can you give me any reference.

Comment: It's in the core documentation under [`DateTime.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse).

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use next:

```
Time.parse('Wed, 29 Jun 2016 11:35 PM')
=> 2016-06-29 23:35:00 +0300
```